# Consulta en PDO con error al hacer echo

Tags: mysql, pdo

resulta que estuve probando unas scripts consideradas "seguras" para hacer consultas SQL, está me interesó, pero no logro entender dónde está el error. Resulta que esta script incluye el fetch, y todo eso, para que directamente haga
`$consult = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM Table")` y después un echo o lo que quisiera hacer con el resultado, no hace falta incluir el execute(), esta es mi consulta

```
$connection = new db("localhost", "basededatos", "root", "");
$consult = $connection->query("SELECT algo FROM cosas");
echo $consult;
```

Lo que me da el siguiente error: **Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\aprendien2\php\sqlscript.php on line 251**

La script es la siguiente:
https://github.com/JamieCressey/php-mysql-pdo-database-class,

```html
<?php
/**
 *  DB - A simple database class 
 *
 * @author      Author: Vivek Wicky Aswal. (https://twitter.com/#!/VivekWickyAswal)
 * @git         https://github.com/indieteq/PHP-MySQL-PDO-Database-Class
 * @version      0.2ab
 *
 */
namespace PDOWrapper;
use \PDO;
class DB
{
    # @var, MySQL Hostname
    private $hostname = 'localhost';
    # @var, MySQL Database
    private $database;
    # @var, MySQL Username
    private $username;
    # @var, MySQL Password
    private $password;
    # @object, The PDO object
    private $pdo;
    # @object, PDO statement object
    private $sQuery;
    # @array,  The database settings
    private $settings;
    # @bool ,  Connected to the database
    private $bConnected = false;
    # @object, Object for logging exceptions    
    private $log;
    # @array, The parameters of the SQL query
    private $parameters;
        
       /**
    *   Default Constructor 
    *
    *   1. Instantiate Log class.
    *   2. Connect to database.
    *   3. Creates the parameter array.
    */
        public function __construct($hostname, $database, $username, $password)
        {           
            $this->Connect($hostname, $database, $username, $password);
            $this->parameters = array();
        }
    
       /**
    *   This method makes connection to the database.
    *   
    *   1. Reads the database settings from a ini file. 
    *   2. Puts  the ini content into the settings array.
    *   3. Tries to connect to the database.
    *   4. If connection failed, exception is displayed and a log file gets created.
    */
        private function Connect($hostname, $database, $username, $password)
        {
            global $settings;
            $dsn = 'mysql:dbname='.$database.';host='.$hostname;
            try 
            {
                # Read settings from INI file, set UTF8
                $this->pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
                
                # We can now log any exceptions on Fatal error. 
                $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                
                # Disable emulation of prepared statements, use REAL prepared statements instead.
                $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, true);
                
                # Connection succeeded, set the boolean to true.
                $this->bConnected = true;
            }
            catch (PDOException $e) 
            {
                # Write into log
                echo $this->ExceptionLog($e->getMessage());
                die();
            }
        }
    /*
     *   You can use this little method if you want to close the PDO connection
     *
     */
        public function CloseConnection()
        {
            # Set the PDO object to null to close the connection
            # http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php
            $this->pdo = null;
        }
        
       /**
    *   Every method which needs to execute a SQL query uses this method.
    *   
    *   1. If not connected, connect to the database.
    *   2. Prepare Query.
    *   3. Parameterize Query.
    *   4. Execute Query.   
    *   5. On exception : Write Exception into the log + SQL query.
    *   6. Reset the Parameters.
    */  
        private function Init($query,$parameters = "")
        {
        # Connect to database
        if(!$this->bConnected) { $this->Connect(); }
        try {
                # Prepare query
                $this->sQuery = $this->pdo->prepare($query);
                
                # Add parameters to the parameter array 
                $this->bindMore($parameters);
                # Bind parameters
                if(!empty($this->parameters)) {
                    foreach($this->parameters as $param)
                    {
                        $parameters = explode("\x7F",$param);
                        $this->sQuery->bindParam($parameters[0],$parameters[1]);
                    }       
                }
                # Execute SQL 
                $this->success = $this->sQuery->execute();      
            }
            catch(PDOException $e)
            {
                    # Write into log and display Exception
                    $this->ExceptionLog($e->getMessage(), $query );
            }
            # Reset the parameters
            $this->parameters = array();
        }
        
       /**
    *   @void 
    *
    *   Add the parameter to the parameter array
    *   @param string $para  
    *   @param string $value 
    */  
        public function bind($para, $value)
        {   
            $this->parameters[sizeof($this->parameters)] = ":" . $para . "\x7F" . utf8_encode($value);
        }
       /**
    *   @void
    *   
    *   Add more parameters to the parameter array
    *   @param array $parray
    */  
        public function bindMore($parray)
        {
            if(empty($this->parameters) && is_array($parray)) {
                $columns = array_keys($parray);
                foreach($columns as $i => &$column) {
                    $this->bind($column, $parray[$column]);
                }
            }
        }
       /**
    *       If the SQL query  contains a SELECT or SHOW statement it returns an array containing all of the result set row
    *   If the SQL statement is a DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement it returns the number of affected rows
    *
    *       @param  string $query
    *   @param  array  $params
    *   @param  int    $fetchmode
    *   @return mixed
    */          
        public function query($query,$params = null, $fetchmode = PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
        {
            $query = trim($query);
            $this->Init($query,$params);
            $rawStatement = explode(" ", $query);
            
            # Which SQL statement is used 
            $statement = strtolower($rawStatement[0]);
            
            if ($statement === 'select' || $statement === 'show') {
                return $this->sQuery->fetchAll($fetchmode);
            }
            elseif ( $statement === 'insert' ||  $statement === 'update' || $statement === 'delete' ) {
                return $this->sQuery->rowCount();   
            }   
            else {
                return NULL;
            }
        }
        
      /**
       *  Returns the last inserted id.
       *  @return string
       */   
        public function lastInsertId() {
            return $this->pdo->lastInsertId();
        }   
        
       /**
    *   Returns an array which represents a column from the result set 
    *
    *   @param  string $query
    *   @param  array  $params
    *   @return array
    */  
        public function column($query,$params = null)
        {
            $this->Init($query,$params);
            $Columns = $this->sQuery->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);     
            
            $column = null;
            foreach($Columns as $cells) {
                $column[] = $cells[0];
            }
            return $column;
            
        }   
       /**
    *   Returns an array which represents a row from the result set 
    *
    *   @param  string $query
    *   @param  array  $params
    *       @param  int    $fetchmode
    *   @return array
    */  
        public function row($query,$params = null,$fetchmode = PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
        {               
            $this->Init($query,$params);
            return $this->sQuery->fetch($fetchmode);            
        }
       /**
    *   Returns the value of one single field/column
    *
    *   @param  string $query
    *   @param  array  $params
    *   @return string
    */  
        public function single($query,$params = null)
        {
            $this->Init($query,$params);
            return $this->sQuery->fetchColumn();
        }
       /**  
    * Writes the log and returns the exception
    *
    * @param  string $message
    * @param  string $sql
    * @return string
    */
}

$connection = new db("localhost", "basededatos", "root", "");
$consult = $connection->query("SELECT algo FROM cosas");
```

Comment: es forzoso que hagas tu conexión a través de ese código?

Comment: ¿Cómo forzoso ?

Comment: que si no e te puede proponer una solución alterna aunque no ocupes ese script que te conecta a la base de datos

Comment: Obviamente que no, cualquier snippet que mas o menos explique una conexión segura con PDO es útil.

Comment: El método `query` que tienes te devuelve un array asociativo. Si lo quieres leer tienes que abrir un bucle. Por ejemplo: `foreach ($consult as $row){echo row["algo"].PHP_EOL;}` en PHP los array no se pueden leer como cadenas, por eso te lanza el mensaje: `Array to string conversion in ...`. Si quieres ver lo que hay dentro del array puedes hacer un `print_r($consult);`, pero esa instrucción no sirve para representar datos legibles como de costumbre.

Comment: Ah si me sirvió, entonces el problema no está en esa script, sino cuando yo quiero darle un uso a la respuesta de la consulta, gracias..

Comment: Correcto, los resultados de todos los métodos que dicen `@return array` deben ser leídos así, mientras que los resultados de los métodos que dicen `@return string` pueden ser leídos con un simple `echo`, porque retornan cadenas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El mensaje:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in ...

ocurre cuanto intentas leer un array como si fuera una cadena.

En el código que muestras, la llamada al método `query` devuelve un array asociativo, donde la clave de cada elemento es el nombre de la columna usada en el `SELECT` y el valor es el dato almacenado en esa columna.

Para presentar los datos que están en el array puedes abrir un bucle `for` del siguiente modo:

```
foreach ($consult as $row){
    echo $row["algo"].PHP_EOL;
}
```

Si tu consulta fuese así:

```
SELECT algo, alguito FROM cosas;
```

Leerías cada valor en `$row` así:

```
foreach ($consult as $row){
    echo $row["algo"]." - ".$row["alguito"].PHP_EOL;
}
```

Para ver lo que hay en el array puedes hacer:

```
print_r($consult);
```

Esto se suele hacer para fines de depuración, más que para presentar los datos de una forma útil al usuario.